# can't show data when refreshing page with jquery-ajaxy

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I try to create an ecommerce website with codeignitier. i'm using ajax to load the picture into div and jquery-ajaxy to show the url, it works well for backward and forward button, but
i got a problem when i refreshed the page, the data can't be show in the div.

is there anyone know why this happen??

controller

> function tesa() {
>         $this->load->view("apricots.html");
>     }
>
> function tesb() {
>         $this->load->view("bananas.html");
>     }
>
> function tesc() {
>         $this->load->view("coconuts.html");
>     }

view

> a href="./index.php/index_con/gambar/Kategori/Sarung/Apple/K001" class="ajaxy ajaxy-page"
>
> Learn about Apricots

Comment: Seems a jquery problem. Code please...

Comment: i don't use jquery code .. this plugin works well in htdocs folder, but when i copied it to my project, this problem occurred

Answer (score 0):

i forget to replace the state on Page Controller's "Matches" in the script ..
problem solved :D
thanks